# Source code for android apps?

Tags: android

I have just started learning to write apps for android using Eclipse. Where can I find free source code that I can use during my learning experience?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The official sample code and tutorials can be found here: http://developer.android.com/resources/index.html

For reading code I can recommend these repositories:

More sample applications for the Android platform: http://code.google.com/p/apps-for-android/

Open Source examples from the books http://commonsware.com/AndTutorials/ and http://commonsware.com/AdvAndroid/ are available at http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-andtutorials and http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/ . They helped me a lot by simply reading the code and searching for classes I needed.

Answer (score 7):

You can take a look at the source code of the common Android applications like Contacts, Email, Calendar, etc.

Look at projects under **platform/packages/apps** here:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/

Comment: [A link that works here](https://github.com/android).

Answer (score 2):

Go to the android developers site, they have lots of code demos and tutorials to get you started. Check em out [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/index.html).

A lot of their examples are included in the sdk. you can find them in android-sdk-windows\samples

Answer (score 1):

You can also reach the code samples directly in Eclipse: create a new Android Project, then select "Create from an existing sample" in the "New Android Project" dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Links where you can spend lots of time learning and checking out Open Source code for eclipse using SVN.

[http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=label:Android](http://code.google.com/hosting/search?q=label%3aAndroid)

https://github.com/search?q=android&ref=commandbar

https://bitbucket.org/repo/all?name=android

Answer (score 0):

Answers are quite old, here is new link to andoird's APS samples http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html